# How to set different visibility_timeout for different queue in celery-sqs

Tags: celery, amazon-sqs, django-celery

I am using celery and sqs for background tasks processing.
We have multiple tasks running, I want to set different visibility_timeout for different tasks; is it possible to do it in settings.py file.
Current settings.py file is

```
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    'region': 'ap-southeast-1',
    'polling_interval': 10,
    'queue_name_prefix': 'dev-',
    'visibility_timeout': 43200,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible a few different ways. I believe the most straight-forward thing you can do for your case is utilize [task routing](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#routing-tasks) capabilities of Celery. The configuration may look something like this

```
app.conf.task_routes = ([
    ('feed.tasks.*', {'queue': 'feeds'}),
    ('web.tasks.*', {'queue': 'web'}),
    (re.compile(r'(video|image)\.tasks\..*'), {'queue': 'media'}),
],)
```

See also: [message routing](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#message-routing).

Alternatively, you can also route tasks 'on-the-fly', overriding the application defaults for the `queue`/`routing_key` on a whim when you send tasks. For example...

```
>>> from feeds.tasks import import_feed
>>> import_feed.apply_async(args=['http://cnn.com/rss'],
...                         queue='feed_tasks',
...                         routing_key='feed.import')
```